# Parallel Plesk and PHP

Tags: php, arrays, plesk

I have tested my new website with BatCave and everything works fine. But when I upload files on Parallel Plesk it seems that it can't recognize php arrays declaration?
I can't find and understand the source of the problem.

Comment: how are you declaring these unrecognized array decelerations. as `[]` or `array()` because `[]`only works  PHP >= 5.4.0

Answer (score 0):

As of  PHP 5.4.0 you can do this

```
$array = [];
```

Prior to that version you have to do this

```
$array = array();
```

Likely that is the issue. Hard to say with no code for example.

Comment: Sure, I've purposely stayed away from using the `[]` in my code, but gesh is it tempting to give in... lol ... it's a very nice feature, just a bit to soon to use it.  Maybe in 1-2 years will be ok.